# R Bug in the Googleway Package

Tags: r, package, googleway

I am using the Googleway package and I don't have any difference between 
"pessimistic", "optimistic" & best_guess" as well as results are similar when mentioning "driving", "walking" or "cycling" modes.
Maybe I am wrong in my code:

```
google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                             destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                             mode="driving",
                             departure_time=heure_dep,
                             traffic_model='best_guess',
                             key = key,
                             simplify = T)
google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                             destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                             mode="bicycling",
                             departure_time=heure_dep,
                             traffic_model='best_guess',
                             key = key,
                             simplify = T)
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, you've found [a bug](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/48). Please try the development version where I've just issued a fix : `devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")`

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed in the latest release version (v2.2.0)

```
google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                                destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                                mode="driving",
                                departure_time=heure_dep,
                                traffic_model='best_guess',
                                key = key,
                                simplify = T)
# ...
# $rows
# elements
# 1 1.3 km, 1308, 6 mins, 368, 5 mins, 292, OK

google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                                destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                                mode="driving",
                                departure_time=heure_dep,
                                traffic_model='pessimistic',
                                key = key,
                                simplify = T)

# ...
# $rows
# elements
# 1 1.3 km, 1308, 6 mins, 368, 5 mins, 293, OK

google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                                destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                                mode="bicycling",
                                departure_time=heure_dep,
                                traffic_model='best_guess',
                                key = key,
                                simplify = T)

# ...
# $rows
# elements
# 1 1.4 km, 1364, 6 mins, 331, OK

google_distance(origins = "place Viarme 44000 nantes",
                                destinations = "rue de strasbourg Nantes",
                                mode="walking",
                                departure_time=heure_dep,
                                traffic_model='best_guess',
                                key = key,
                                simplify = T)
# ...
# $rows
# elements
# 1 1.2 km, 1187, 15 mins, 915, OK
```